# Ratios in matrix | Matrix/Vector | if statement/loop |

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement

I was wondering how would you explain below function to work with matrix instead of vector input, essentially I just find all values that is over a certain value in that column and add it up and divide it by total rows to give me ratio. Below is working for vector input but I kinda not sure how to complete the one with matrix input. Should I use `logical` instead?

The method I chosen don't think will work if there is more than 2 columns but I wish it could accommodate any size.

```
function Ratio = ratiovector(Vector)

N = numel(Vector);
c=0

for a = 1:N

    if Vectors(a) >= 20
        c=c + 1;
    end
    end


Ratio = c/N;
end
```

Matrix Input

```
function Ratio = ratiovector2(Matrix)

rows = Matrix(:,1)
columns = Matrix(:,2)
c = 0
d = 0

for a = 1:rows
    for b =1:columns

    if Matrix(a) >= 20
        c= c + 1;
    if Matrix(b) >= 20
        d= d + 1;
    end
    end


Ratio = ?;
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You clarified in the comments that you want the number of elements in each column over a threshold, over the number of rows in the matrix.

This is a quick one-liner (where the threshold is 20):

```
ratio = sum(M>20, 1) / size(M, 1);
```

Breaking this down, we have

```
    M > 20;                 % logical array which is 1 where M > 20, 0 otherwise
sum(M > 20, 1);             % column-wise sum of the logical
sum(M > 20, 1) / size(M,1)  % Divide the sum by the number of rows to get ratio.
```

This will work for any column vector or matrix.

Example:

```
M = [10, 15, 20, 100
     21,  0, 21, 101
      0,  0, 21, 102];

ratio = sum(M>20, 1) / size(M, 1);
% >> ratio = [0.333..., 0.0, 0.666..., 1.0] = [1/3, 0/3, 2/3, 3/3]
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not very clear to me how you want to normalize your ratio, but the function below is a starting point, and it works for matrices and vectors. It uses logical indexing rather than for-loops, which should probably have better performance.

```
M = [0  1  2  5  22 ; 
     32 1  1  7  22 ; 
     10 10 10 10 20];

Ratio = ratiovector2(M)


function Ratio = ratiovector2(Matrix)

    % This will give you a boolean matrix the same size of Matrix, with
    % true values where Matrix elements are higher than 20
    detected = Matrix > 20;

    % The ratio is "how many are over 20 in each column"
    Ratio = sum(detected) ./ size(Matrix,1);
end
```

If you need a function AND you like one-liners, here you go:

```
ratiovector3 = @(Matrix)sum(Matrix > 20) ./ size(Matrix,1);

Ratio = ratiovector3(M)
```

Comment: Yes, It will display a ratio of many elements are over 20 for each columns. 

edit:
For example: M should ouput something like [1/3 0/3 0/3 0/3 3/3]

Comment: If it's not clear to you then comment for clarification, this helps prevent questions from having redundant answers once the OP clarifies. Save answering for when you know you have the answer